# WildFly-9.0.2.Final war file deployment very slow

Tags: java, wildfly, application-server, wildfly-9

I am trying to deploy a war file in WildFly 9.0.2, but it's taking a very long time and throwing a `TimeoutException`. I also increased the transaction timeout, which had been `300`.

Any advice?

Comment: What does the term usage, "*get deployed*" stand for, in this case?

Comment: Did you check logs for error/exceptions?If so, can you paste stacktrace.